# Change Shipping method TITLE after order in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I want change the shipping method title (view image) after create the order. I using hook "woocommerce_thankyou", but i can't change the title of existing shipping.

[image with i want change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUbzr.png)

I find this code, but with this code add a new shipping method but it's not what i want, because after this code i have 2 shipping method.

```
$item = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();
$item->set_method_title( "SEUR Estándar" );
$item->set_method_id( "seur" ); // set an existing Shipping method rate ID
//$item->set_total( $new_ship_price ); // (optional)
//$item->calculate_taxes($calculate_tax_for);

$order->add_item( $item );

$order->save();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the shipping method TITLE only in admin area ?

For example :
=> In WC settings, shipping method title = SEUR Estándar (this title is displayed to customers during checkout and on emails)
=> In WC admin, when you handle the order, you want SEUR Estándar is changed to SEUR

For this, you can try something like that (not tested), hooking only the displayed title

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_method_title', function( $method_title, $method_id ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() || ! 'shop_order' === get_post_type() ) { // change applied only on admin order page
        return $method_title;
    }
    if ( $method_id == 'seur' ) { // change condition to match what you need
        $method_title = 'SEUR'; // new method title
    }
    return $method_title;
}, 10, 2 );
```

If you want to change the shipping method title in other areas, think about what it is easier and need less job : change only for customer in front end, change only for admin, change in emails... ? Then adapt conditions in above snippet.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you very much for your answer, I will try to be more specific in my question.

SEUR has 2 method_title for 1 single method_id, the reason is that the plugin no longer communicates with woocommerce.

For the SEUR hotline, the solution is to change it manually once the order has been completed by the customer in "woocommerce -> my orders".

I try to make that change automatically so that the administrator doesn't have to do it.

->continue in next comment

Comment: The idea is that when the order is finished by default the method_title is SEUR, under a certain condition "if cart does not contain fresh product", when reaching the end of the order which I understand is the hook "woocommerce_thanyou", I want to put that conditional and if the cart does not contain a fresh product, so just change the method_title, and there comes my problem with the previous code that I put, add a new entry and what I want is to modify the one that already exists.

Thanks

Comment: If you change the method_title of your WC_Shipping_Method programmaticaly under any hook ("woocommerce_thanyou" for example), this change will be applied globally. So every others customers will see this change when choosing shipping method. =>

Comment: That's why I suggested to you to change the **displayed** method_title with 'woocommerce_shipping_method_title' hook and add your own logic in. You should add an order meta calculated under "woocommerce_thanyou" to know what title to display.

Comment: Another suggestion is to create in woocommerce settings the second Shipping Method with the changed title. Hide this method to customers choice and change the Shipping_method for the order if conditions match under "woocommerce_thanyou" hook.

Comment: First of all Jo Kolov, I want to thank you for your help that little by little has been giving me a solution to the problem I had. Here I put the solution and greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I find this solucion and thanks for all Jo Kolov

```
foreach($rates as $rate_id => $rate) { 
    if ( 'seur' === $rate->method_id ) {
        $rates[$rate_id]->label = __( 'SEUR Estándar', 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
```